# Book on measure theory for the layman

Tags: measure-theory, book-recommendation

Though unlikely for such a technical topic, is there a book on measure theory (and/or Lebesgue integration) for the casual learner? I am especially interested in the history: the motivation behind the theory, how it came to be, why mathematicians felt they needed some other tool, and how it was developed. Easy examples that would make a self-learner "tick" would be great.

Comment: Measure theory proper or Lebesgue integration? For the latter, there's *Bressoud's A Radical Approach to Lebesgue's Theory of Integration* which gives plenty of motivation and historical developments (it's still an introductory *textbook* though, so you'll probably need to work a few exercises along the way to get the most of it)

Comment: @Weaam Thanks for the comment. Edited the post accordingly.

Comment: You could look at "A Garden of Integrals" by Franke E. Burk. It is a bit different from what you are asking for, but it does place the Lebesgue integral and measure in the context of the general history of integration.

Comment: Hawkins's *Lebesgue's Theory of Integration: Its Origins and Development* is nice, but perhaps doesn't qualify as a layman's book.